# file upload chown/chgrp permission issue in php/zend

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, permissions, chown

I have issue after file uploaded to linux server, i am uploading file in Zend Framework(PHP),

issue is that when i upload file then it takes apache owner/group permission, but its should be same owner/group permission as parent folder,

For ex. per folder permission like

**-rwxrwxrwx 1 *username* *username* 1000 2013-06-10 20:03 tempFolder** (owner/group permission is username/username)

but when i upload file name temp.txt into tempFolder folder, it takes default apache owner/group permission as following,

**-rwxrwxrwx 1 *apache* *apache* 1000 2013-06-10 20:03 temp.txt**

so i want to temp.txt owner/group permission same as tempFolder

Please help as soon as possible,

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I think you can achieve this with a sticky bit on the parent folder.

Comment: whats exactly problem i am fixing thats i dont know, because i m not server guy.